# How to choose linux compiler and simplify this azure-pipeline script?

Tags: c++, cmake, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Setup different compilers for cmake; 
Colorize build results.

my current pipeline script for linux ('Hosted Ubuntu 1604'):

```
  steps:
 - script: 'cp CMakeLists.txt build/'
    displayName: 'cp cmakelist'
 - script: 'export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-7'
    displayName: 'set gcc version'
 - script: 'export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-7'
    displayName: 'set g++ version'
 - script: 'cmake CMakeLists.txt'
    displayName: 'cmake'
 - script: 'make AllTest'
    displayName: 'Build AllTest'
 - script: 'cd lib/all_test'
    displayName: 'set all test directory'
 - script: './AllTest'
    workingDirectory: lib/all_test/
    displayName: 'run AllTest'
```

My problems:

1. CMake@1 works well in windows, but this command expect the cMakeLists.txt in the build directory
2. I've listed the available compilers and gcc 7 is available, but even I tried to setup to use it, the cmake uses gcc 5.4, how can I select different compilers e.g gcc 7, clang (in windows I use cmake -G Visual Studio...
3. I use a standalone test library (rili tests/ c++) , and on the azure servers the test results has no color, how can I colorize my test results?

Comment: I have no idea about Azure, but what catches my eye is the `- script: 'cmake CMakeLists.txt'` line. That’s not how you call CMake. You cd to the build directory and then call CMake with the path to the *directory* where CMakeLists.txt is located, not with the path to the file itself.